# VectorDisplacementPlot is stuck in certain geometries

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, regions, mesh

I want to plot some deformation fields on some geometries with two holes. I do it using VectorDisplacementPlot. In some of the cases the distance between the holes is very small (for example: holeDistance=2.1), and in those cases the calculation time diverges, and after a few minutes the program sometimes even crash. On the other hand, in most of the cases (for example holeDistance=2.8) the VectorDisplacementPlot have no problems.
To be clear - I found out this problem occur regardless of the deformation field being plotted. It has problems even computing the deformation field of f={1,0}.

**Here is the code I used:**

```
holeDistance = 2.1;
holeRadius = 1;
Reg = Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {3, 3}];
Reg = RegionDifference[Reg, Disk[{-holeDistance/2, 0}, holeRadius]];
Reg = RegionDifference[Reg, Disk[{holeDistance/2, 0}, holeRadius]];

RegionPlot[Reg, PlotLabel -> "holeDistance=2.1"]

f = {1, 0};

VectorDisplacementPlot[f, {u, v} \[Element] Reg]
```

[image: holeDistance=2.8. No problems with the plot.]

[image: holeDistance=2.1. The program fail to calculate the plot.]

Answer (score 4):

If you can discretize the region before plotting, you should be able to use the discretization:

```
dreg = DiscretizeRegion[reg, 
   MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 0.09000000112999323`}];
VectorDisplacementPlot[f, {u, v} \[Element] dreg]
```

[image]

The `"Area"` constraint was taken from

```
Trace[
 VectorDisplacementPlot[f, {u, v} \[Element] reg],
 r_DiscretizeRegion,
 TraceInternal -> True
 ]
```

It's roughly 1/400 of the area of the bounding rectangle.

Comment: It works amazing! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

- Seems be a bug. It work in v13.3

```
$Version
(* 13.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 3, 2023) *)

Clear[reg];
holeDistance = 2.1;
holeRadius = 1; 
reg = 
 Fold[RegionDifference, {Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {3, 3}], 
   Disk[{-holeDistance/2, 0}, holeRadius], 
   Disk[{holeDistance/2, 0}, holeRadius]}];
f = {1, 0};
VectorDisplacementPlot[f, {u, v} ∈ reg]
```

- Here we also test v13.3 by using `CSGRegion`,

```
Clear[reg];
holeDistance = 2.1;
holeRadius = 1;
reg = 
 Fold[CSGRegion[
    "Difference", {#1, #2}] &, {Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {3, 3}], 
   Disk[{-holeDistance/2, 0}, holeRadius], 
   Disk[{holeDistance/2, 0}, holeRadius]}]
f = {1, 0};
VectorDisplacementPlot[f, {u, v} ∈ reg]
```

[image]

Comment: Well unfortunately I have version 13.2